# How to prove $\frac{\tan (A)}{\tan (A)}+\frac{\cot (A)}{\cot (A)}=\frac{1}{1-2\cos(A)^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I am unable to prove this trigonometric identity

$$\frac{\tan (A)}{\tan (A)}+\frac{\cot (A)}{\cot (A)}=\frac{1}{1-2\cos^2(A)}$$

I have tried to transform the left-hand side and stuck with this

$$\frac{2\sin(A)\cos(A)}{\sin(A)\cos(A)}$$

And I have tried to transform the right-hand side by changing the $$2\cos^2(A)$$ to $$\frac{2}{\sec^2(A)}$$, and used the trigonometric identity $$1+\tan^2(A)=\sec^2(A)$$ and got this instead

$$\frac{1+\tan^2(A)}{\tan^2(A)-1}$$ which I can transform to $$\frac{\cot(A)+\tan(A)}{\tan(A)-\cot(A)}$$.

I cannot get both sides equal, help please?

Comment: I think there's a typo as the left side is always $1 + 1 = 2$, so it's independent of $A$,  while the right side is definitely not a constant.

Comment: @JohnOmielan but that's exactly how the question on textbook is written?

Comment: Then your textbook must have a typo, because this identity clearly can not be proven true.

Comment: @JohnOmielan does that mean every equation that has a dependent variable on one side and a constant on the other side cannot be proven?

Comment: @NobleMushtak I see, thank you for the answer. That must be the case, the book is so old

Comment: @user569622 No, it just means that the dependent variable usually cannot be fully variable but, instead, must have a value so the value of its side of the equation matches.  This usually limits the possible set of values to either a small finite # (e.g., 0, 1 or 2) or a specific set (e.g., for trigonometric functions, $+ 2k\pi$, for all integral values of $k$).

Comment: You check whether a given identity is false by plotting each side of the identity as separate functions, e.g. on desmos.com. if the graphs don't match up then you know something must be wrong.

Comment: @Antinous oh, i see. that is useful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way we can prove the identity false is as follows:

$$\begin {align}
\dfrac {\tan A} {\tan A} + \dfrac{\cot A}{\cot A} = \dfrac {1}{1-2\cos^2 2A} \\
2 = \dfrac {1}{1-2\cos^2 2A} \\
2 (1-2\cos^2 2A) = 1 \\
2 - 4\cos^2 2A = 1 \\
- 4\cos^2 2A = \dfrac {1}{2} \\
\cos^2 2A = -\dfrac {1}{8}
\end {align}$$

Since the last line would require us to take the square root of a negative number, $A$ does not exist, and the identity is false.